# Can we use PhoneGap for Mobile Sites Development?

Tags: html, browser, mobile, cordova

Can any one please suggest me the way to develop the Mobile sites .We already have the Main Desktop site and want to develop the mobile versions so what is the best way to developed the mobile version of the site. My site is based on Joomla but i did not find any module full fill our requirement now i want to know one thing more is there any way to develop the mobile site using some software which use API of my main site to access the data base because i have API because i already develop my native app for iPHONE and ANDROID.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no.. because Phonegap uses a native library (plug-in) to make things works, for example you have to include phonegap.jar for android projects. And in your website you cant include native code..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)